# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: getTestCaseByName for class:

Tags: groovy, soapui

Did any one face this issue? is there any solution for this?

To run the **step** InvalidLoginAttempt from test case **session** I have tried the below script

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Session").runTestStepByName("InvalidLoginAttempt")
```

It was throwing

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.runTestStepByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: **[InvalidLoginAttempt]** Possible solutions: getTestStepByName(java.lang.String), getTestStepByName(java.lang.String) error at line: 4

So tried changing

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Session").runTestStepByName["InvalidLoginAttempt"]
```

getting below error.

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: runTestCaseByName for class: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite error at line: 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried in the below and it got worked..:)

```
def r = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Session").getTestStepByName("InvalidLoginAttempt").run(testRunner, context);
```